# My app consume too much battery in background

Tags: android, battery

In my settings, I saw that my app is marked as "Frequent failures" in battery settings in the background. It is a quiz app.
My question is what makes my app running in the background?

I don't use location services.
I use tools like Glide, Shared Preferences but I don't know what tool runs in the background when my app is closed...

My phone is on API 29.

EDIT: I use in an activity a `Handler.postDelayed()` maybe it continues in the background?

Comment: How can we possibly know what your app is doing?

Comment: Handler will not work in background if process is dead. Use https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/battery-historian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use in an activity a Handler.postdelayed() maybe it continues in background?

Yes, if there's a runnable which is scheduled to run after some time, it will definitely run even if your app is in the background (but not dead).

Hence, to save resources, call `nameOfTheHandler.removeCallbacks(nameOfTheRunnable)` inside the activity's onPause() method.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    nameOfTheHandler.removeCallbacks(nameOfTheRunnable)
}
```

For more info checkout [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) documentation.